# using subclass attribute in the main class in python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to set the self.role under credential class to use the self.role under AXL class. the idea is to have different classes based on the role the api needs to be. if axl class is only reading data then the role would be r.

```
PATH = 'home_drive_'
PLATFORM = 'Linux_'
ITEM = '_PC'

class Credential:

    def __init__(self, path, platform):
        self.role = 'rx'
        self.username_file = path + platform + ('The role should be the same as AXL role: ' + self.role)

class AXL(Credential):

    def __init__(self, path, platform, item):
        super().__init__(path, platform)
        self.role = 'r'
        self.item = item

    def final(self):
        return self.username_file + self.item

reg1 = AXL(PATH, PLATFORM, ITEM)

print('AXL role:', reg1.role)
print(reg1.username_file)
print(reg1.final())
```

the result would be

```
AXL role: r 
home_drive_Linux_The role should be the same as AXL role: rx 
home_drive_Linux_The role should be the same as AXL role: rx_PC
```

Instead of rx, I need to see r

Here is a [link](https://repl.it/@louis_philippedescamps/using-subclass-attribute-in-the-main-class?language=python3&folderId=) to the sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`role` should be an parameter of `Credential.__init__`, not hard-coded, although it could have a default value for the base class. Subclasses would pass the required role directly to `super().__init__`. (If there is something that *must* have a role of `'rx'`, that should be a subclass of `Credential` as well, not `Credential` itself.)

```
class Credential:

    def __init__(self, path, platform, role='rx'):
        self.role = role
        self.username_file = path + platform + ('The role should be the same as AXL role: ' + role)


# class SomethingNeedingRoleRX(Credential):
#      def __init__(self, path, platform):
#          super().__init__(path, platform, 'rx')


class AXL(Credential):

    def __init__(self, path, platform, item):
        super().__init__(path, platform, 'r')
        self.item = item

    def final(self):
        return self.username_file + self.item
```

To play nicer with `super`, you might consider using keyword-only arguments for `__init__`:

```
class Credential:
    def __init__(self, *, path, platform, role='rx', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.role = role
        self.username_file = path + platform + role


class AXL(Credential):
    def __init__(self, *, item, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(role='r', **kwargs)
        self.item = item

    def final(self):
        return self.username_file + self.item


reg1 = AXL(path=PATH, platform=PLATFORM, item=ITEM)
```

Comment: That defines `path` et al. as keyword-only arguments. It's no longer legal to say `AXL(PATH, PLATFORM)`, since `AXL.__init__` takes no positional arguments (aside from `self`). Using keyword arguments means you don't have to worry about positional arguments conflicting with each other in later descendants of `Credential`.

Comment: what if I want to set role='r' under the def final(self)?

Answer (score 2):

[Answer by @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55299983/6560549) is definitely correct solution. I’ll leave this here as a homage to over complicating a simple problem.

You could make `username_file` a [`@property`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) on `Credential` so it’s evaluated on access not on instance creation.

```
class Credential:
    def __init__(self, path, platform):
        self.role = 'rx'
        self.path = path
        self.platform = platform

    @property
    def username_file(self):
        return self.path + self.platform + self.role
```

If it’s an instance of `AXL` roll will be ‘r’ and ‘rx’ if instance of `Credential`.

You can also cache the result of the first property access if you want to streamline:

```
class Credential:
    def __init__(self, path, platform):
        self.role = 'rx'
        self.path = path
        self.platform = platform
        self._username_file = None

    @property
    def username_file(self):
        if not self._usernme_file:
            self._username_file = self.path + self.platform + self.role
        return self._username_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem here is basically the data type of `username_file`; its a string created in the constructor and does not update when it's components do. There are a few ways to go around this, using properties is a pretty good and clean way to go about it:

```
PATH = 'home_drive_'
PLATFORM = 'Linux_'
ITEM = '_PC'


class Credential:
    def __init__(self, path, platform):
        self.path = path
        self.platform = platform
        self.role = 'rx'
        self.username_file = self.path + self.platform + ('The role should be the same as AXL role: ' + self.role)

    @property
    def role(self):
        return self._role

    @role.setter
    def role(self, new_role):
        self._role = new_role
        self.username_file = self.path + self.platform + ('The role should be the same as AXL role: ' + self.role)


class AXL(Credential):
    def __init__(self, path, platform, item):
        super().__init__(path, platform)
        self.role = 'r'
        self.item = item

    def final(self):
        return self.username_file + self.item


reg1 = AXL(PATH, PLATFORM, ITEM)

print('AXL role:', reg1.role)
print(reg1.username_file)
print(reg1.final())
```

**EDIT:**

Just a short explanation, you can turn to a property pretty much any variable, the reason for selecting role is resource management.
Essentially, it takes fewer resources to update `username_file` in the setter every time role changes (once in the program) than add strings (slow operation) every time you call the getter. Of course, considering the size of the program resource management should not be a deal breaker, but mentioning to explain the logic of the answer.

Comment: what if I want to define the role in the final method?

Comment: with properties you can change anytime, so either works really! you can change role anywhere in the code, not just the constructor. this will also update the username_file attribute to the appropriate role

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeDescamps see example [here](https://repl.it/@nickthefreak/Inheritance), you can set role anywhere to any string

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers, but we're missing something obvious: [class attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

```
class Credential:
    role = 'rx'

    def __init__ (...
    # (... rest of class definition)

class AXL(Credential):
    role = 'r'

    def __init__ (...
    # (... rest of class definition)
```

If you want the quick answer: just remove the `self.role = ...` lines from the `__init__` functions, and instead have these `role = ...` lines in as class attributes.

If you want the detailed answer: keep reading :)

#### The problem

The main problem lies in the last two lines of the `__init__` function for Credential. First, it sets `self.role` to `'rx'`, and then it uses `self.role` to compute a value of `self.username_file`. From the point of view of the `AXL` class, this sets the wrong value for both attributes.

AXL needs to fix the value of `self.role` *after* Credential sets it to `'rx'`, but *before* Credential uses it to set the value of `username_file`. But it can't. Your problem is that these two things are happening right next to each other in Credential's `__init__` function. There's no space in-between for AXL to intervene and change the result.

To fix the problem, one of these assignments needs to be moved out of Credential's `__init__` function. The previous answers all decided to move `username_file`. But in my humble opinion, it's easier and better to move `role`. Instead of setting `username_file` after the init function, we're going to set `role` *before* the init function.

#### Class attributes

When the interpreter encounters a line like `self.role = 'rx'`, it sets an instance attribute. This means that each particular Credential object gets its own personal value for `role`. They're all stored separately, even if they all happen to be copies of the same string.

In your case, it looks like you want every Credential object to have the exact same `role` as every other Credential object, and every AXL object to have the same role as every other AXL object. That's a perfect use case for a class attribute.

Class attributes are attributes that you define on the class itself, instead of on the individual instances. Importantly for our purposes, you can set them just once, when the class is defined. You don't have to set them again every time in the `__init__` function.

[I found a pretty good article on class attributes here](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide).

#### The fixed Code

```
PATH = 'home_drive_'
PLATFORM = 'Linux_'
ITEM = '_PC'

class Credential:
    role = 'rx'

    def __init__(self, path, platform):    
        self.username_file = path + platform + ('The role should be the same as AXL role: ' + self.role)

class AXL(Credential):
    role = 'r'

    def __init__(self, path, platform, item):
        super().__init__(path, platform)
        self.item = item

    def final(self):
        return self.username_file + self.item

reg1 = AXL(PATH, PLATFORM, ITEM)

print('AXL role:', reg1.role)
print(reg1.username_file)
print(reg1.final())
```

[sandbox](https://replit.com/@DouglasWinship/using-subclass-attribute-in-the-main-class)

#### How it works

First, the interpreter executes the class definition for Credential, which creates the class and sets the class attribute `Credential.role` to `'rx'`. An `__init__` function is defined, but it isn't run.

Then the interpreter executes the the class definition for AXL. As before it creates the class and sets the class attribute. This time the attribut is `AXL.role`, and it's set to `'r'`.

At last, an `AXL` object is created, called reg1. This is when `AXL.__init__` is actualy run, and in turn it runs `Credential.__init__`.

Here's where it gets fun. Credential's `__init__` function tries to access `self.role`. `self` is the reg1 object, so the interpreter tries to look up `reg1.role`. `reg1` doesn't have a `role` attribute itself, but it's an instance of the AXL class, and the *class* does have a `role` attribute, so the interpreter substitutes the value of `AXL.role` for `self.role`, and gets a value of `'r'`.

That last part is the interesting bit. Even though we're inside *Credential*'s `__init__`, the `self` object is an instance of *AXL*, so `AXL.role` is the value we want. And that's the value we get.